# Playwright JS , how to intercept on HTTP calls on button click

Tags: cypress, playwright, playwright-test, cypress-intercept

I am new to Playwright, need some help on intercepting http calls.

I have scenario, on clicking on button , will get 2 requests
request 1 -> baseurl/session/
request 2 -> sessiondata

I need to verify if request1 got 200 response and also from request 2 I need to validate request payload. In cypress I can achieve this by:

```js
cy.intercept(request1).as(req1)
cy.intecpt(requrest2).as (req2)
cy.get(button).click()
cy.get(req1) .its('response.statusCode')
      .should('eq', 200);
cy.get(req2).its("request.body")
        .then((body) => {
console.log(body);
});
```

I am struggling to achieve the same in Playwright, confused with waitforRequest & waitforResponse,

---

Thanks for response, but getting I am request body is `[obj][obj]`, request2.header is undefined, what am I missing here?

```js
const requestPromise1 = this.page.waitForResponse((res) => 
  res.url().includes("url1")&& res.status() === 202);
const requestPromise2 = this.page.waitForResponse((res) => 
  res.url().includes("url2")&& res.status() === 204);

await page.locator("<button locator>").click();
                                                                                
const request1 = await requestPromise1;
const request2 = await requestPromise2;

expect(request1.status()).toBe(202);
expect(request2.status()).toBe(204);

console.log("headerheader"+request2.header)
console.log("request2"+await request2.request());
```

Note: Url1 is POST , Url2 is PATCH with 204 response from which I need to get payload

Comment: I don't see any Playwright code attempt here. Can you share it, preferably along with the actual site, a runnable, complete [mcve] and a package.json? Thanks.

Comment: const requestPromise2 = page.waitForResponse((res) => res.url().includes("url2")&& 
   res.status() === 204);
  await page.locator("button").click();                                                                                
    const request1 = await requestPromise1;
        const request2 = await requestPromise2;
        console.log(request2.request());

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show the code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way in Playwright to acomplish exactly what you did while using Cypress.

Here I'm using `waitForResponse` method to intercept those requests, clicking the btn, checking the status, and finally extracting the request body using `res.json()`.

As mentioned in earlier answer, make sure you do not `await` the `waitForResponse` functions:

```js
test("intercept http requests on click", async ({ page }) => {
  // Intercept requests
  const responsePromise1 = page.waitForResponse("/endpoint1"); // no await
  const responsePromise2 = page.waitForResponse("/endpoint2"); // no await

  // Click your button
  await page.locator("<button locator>").click();

  // Await those intercepted requests now
  const response1 = await responsePromise1;
  const response2 = await responsePromise2;

  // Check requests status
  expect(response1.status()).toBe(200);
  expect(response2.status()).toBe(200);

  // Get the request's body and print it
  const data = await response2.json();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I tried similar one , but request body is [obj][obj] , any idea

Answer (score -1):

[Playwright can use `waitForResponse`.](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#network-events) The general workflow is to define the wait as a variable, do the action that triggers the network request, then await the wait.

```js
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse('/call-1'); // note no 'await' here
await page.getByText('button').click();
const response = await responsePromise;
```

Then `response` variable is a Playwright `Response` type, which means we can check the status from that variable. I think the easiest way would be to just use `.ok()`, which "Contains a boolean stating whether the response was successful (status in the range 200-299) or not."

```js
expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();
```

If we needed to check a specific status number, we could use `.status()`.

```js
expect(response.status()).toEqual(200);
```

Additionally, if you need the request associated with the response, that can be found by `.request()`

```js
const { foo } = response.request().postDataJSON();
expect(foo).toEqual('foo');
```